# Workflow not starting for second item added

Tags: designer-workflow

I have created a SharePoint 2010 designer workflow for document approval everything works as per designed when an item is added for the first time. Workflows completes as designed.But when I add second item the workflow shows directly completed without following the steps. What would be cause and how to resolve this?
Please find the screen shot below for the steps I tried through workflow 
[image]

Comment: Hard to say without looking into the logic of your workflow! Maybe it is a condition in the beginning of the workflow that is not met so the workflow completes right away. I would try and log steps and variables to the history list and see if you can figure it out... Good Luck!

Comment: hi ahmed please find the edited question with screenshot of what I am trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to it finally added wait condition before the start of the workflow in the first step and now it works as required.

[image]